# Why can't the dotnet cli 3.x build a docker image?

Tags: docker, .net-core

I've got a build script which was designed for dotnet 2.1. This script's job is to output a docker image that runs a dotnet core app. I recently made a small change to the dotnet core app but when I went to build a container, using my script, the image didn't work. I debugged this down to dotnet 3.1 behaving differently when calling the dotnet publish command...

Here is the command I'm using in dotnet 2.1:

```
dotnet publish WebService      --configuration %CONFIGURATION% --output bin\Docker
```

This creates a Docker folder in the bin folder, as expected, but when I use dotnet 3.1 this output argument appears to be ignored.

I found this on the following on MSDN:

> If you're using an SDK that is newer, like 3.0, make sure that your
>   app is forced to use the 2.2 SDK. Create a file named global.json in
>   your working folder and paste in the following JSON code:
>
> {   "sdk": {
>       "version": "2.2.100"   } }

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container

So, after finding this info on MSDN that says that I need to force dotnet to use an older version, I now have a workaround but my question is... why? Dotnet 3.1 can't build Docker images? Please help me connect the dots on what I'm missing here.

Comment: This is just a guess, but I assume that between 3.1 and 2.2 the publish and docker image build operations didn't change at all so you just target the old version. I think they should probably fix this so that when the publish is called it can intuitively point to the 2.2 version if indeed what I said is true. Shouldn't have to specify old versions if that's the only supported version. That should be the default.

Comment: @PeonProgrammer. I like your Stack Overflow handle.

Comment: I checked publish command and for both 2.1 and 3.1 I files published to folder defined in `--output` option. The question in last paragraph is a bit wrong. You publish here compialed app to given folder and not buil a Docker image.